# How do I delete a tumblr blog?

Tags: blog, tumblr

I have 2 tumblr blogs, and one of them I didn't mean to make, is there a way to completly delete it from my account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Deleting a blog**
>   To delete a blog, all of its members must leave it. If you are the blog's only member, simply open it in the Dashboard and click Members. You will see a button to Leave this blog.
>   Your primary blog cannot be deleted without closing your entire account.
>
> **Deleting your Tumblr account**
>   You can delete your account at any time.
>   When closing your account, your primary blog will be deleted as well as any additional blogs you are the only member of. Any group blogs with other members will not be affected.

[Source](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/blogs)

Comment: Seems to be one of those RTFM situations... Thanks!

Comment: @Rixius - we all have those.

Answer (score 1):

Simply go to http://www.tumblr.com/preferences and look for the **Delete Your Account** link below.

If you want to delete a specific tumbelog,

1. Click on that tumblelog **http://www.tumblr.com/tumblelog/TUMBLELOGYOUWANTTODELETE**
2. Click **Members**, also http://www.tumblr.com/tumblelog/TUMBLELOGYOUWANTTODELETE/members
3. Click, **Leave this blog**.