# Why won't Tumblr delete one of my additional blogs?

Tags: tumblr

I’m trying to delete two of my Tumblr blogs, both of them additional to my primary blog. Every time I hit delete when managing accounts, Tumblr says "not found." Neither one of my blogs has any members, and I've tried deleting it through settings, deleting it through the members link on the dashboard, and I've copied and pasted the URL into a different tab in my browser. None of that works; Tumblr keeps saying it can't find my blog!

Comment: Here is a question&answer how it should normally work: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3278/how-do-i-delete-a-tumblr-blog - I've no idea why it doesn't work for you, though.

Comment: And here is the same problem: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/33784/my-tumblr-account-wont-deactivate

Answer (score 1):

As much as it is banal, send an email to `support@tumblr.com`—this looks like bug and it is up to the admin to delete the blog when something prevents you in clear execution of target.